# Nginx Rewrite Multiple Rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I am trying to move my server to Nginx for trial purposes. However, when I transfer my htaccess codes to conf file, I get 404 error. How can I make the codes below Nginx rewrite compatible?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^firmaekle\.html$ /firmaekle.php [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/d/([^/]*).([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?site=$1&site2=$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]*)([^/]*)\.html$ /uzgun.php?site=$1&site2=$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^y/([^/]*)([^/]*)\.html$ /yonlendir.php?firma=$1&uzanti=$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ye/([^/]*)([^/]*)\.html$ /yonlendir2.php?firma=$1&uzanti=$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: This ruleset is so simple, you can safely use some automatic converter for it. [One of the best](https://www.getpagespeed.com/apache-to-nginx) is written by [Danila Vershinin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285069/danila-vershinin).

Comment: 404 error persists even though I've added rewrite codes 

https://gist.github.com/EmreKara5aya/ca67b906d623d5b10c97745a620aabce

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    rewrite ^/firmaekle\.html$ /firmaekle.php permanent;

    rewrite ^//d/([^/]*).([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?site=$1&site2=$2 permanent;

    rewrite ^/u/([^/]*)([^/]*)\.html$ /uzgun.php?site=$1&site2=$2 permanent;

    rewrite ^/y/([^/]*)([^/]*)\.html$ /yonlendir.php?firma=$1&uzanti=$2 permanent;

    rewrite ^/ye/([^/]*)([^/]*)\.html$ /yonlendir2.php?firma=$1&uzanti=$2 permanent;
}
```

Comment: I added the codes to the conf file and restarted Nginx. However, I still get 404 not found error. Conf codes: https://gist.github.com/EmreKara5aya/ca67b906d623d5b10c97745a620aabce

Comment: add them out of the `location` here https://gist.github.com/EmreKara5aya/ca67b906d623d5b10c97745a620aabce#file-nginx-conf-L44

Comment: I added the codes where you said, but I still get the 404 error.

Comment: what is the  output of this command `curl http://127.0.0.1/firmaekle.html -v` (replace the ip it is on another host)

Comment: and are you sure that the `firmaekle.php` exists in the root  folder `/home/nginx/domains/domkap.com/public`

Comment: curl https://domkap.com/d/afafafafa.com.html -v output: https://gist.github.com/EmreKara5aya/fd44af18ec7ac57254c8cf10ebacb997

Comment: The files appear in the /home/nginx/domains/domkap.com/public folder.